# Maven provided scope deployed on Juno + Tomcat 7

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, tomcat7

Perhaps not a Maven issue then. m2e / wtp issue, maybe?

Just to give a background, I set up an ICEFaces project in Eclipse and deployed it in Tomcat 7.0.30. It appears the Maven POM configuration for servlet-api.jar to be in provided scope is disregarded while deploying to Tomcat. Am I missing anything? How do I get Maven to do it right?

In the project **javax.servlet-api.jar** is pulled in as a transitive dependency of ICEFaces. Since Tomcat comes with it's own servlet-api.jar I marked it to be excluded and added an explicit dependency (scope:provided).

> INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.30
>   06-Mar-2013 10:44:05 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
>   INFO: validateJarFile(D:\workspaces\test-project\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\test-project\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
>   06-Mar-2013 10:44:07 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized

**Maven POM**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
  <artifactId>icefaces-ace</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

And added a dependency with provided scope

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Setup:
* Eclipse Juno
* Maven webapp project was created.
* JSF and ICEFaces facets were enabled and configured.
* Configured the Eclipse project's Deployment Assembly to deploy Maven dependencies.
* Deploying the project to Tomcat from Eclipse (Right click in servers tab> Add/Remove > add the project > Publsh)

*** Update 1 ***

**mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose**

Don't know what to do about these warnings. I'll look up on how to enable debug logging.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...  
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test-project Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ test-project ---
[WARNING] The POM for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.0.4 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details  
[WARNING] The POM for classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-8 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] com.mochapenguin:test-project:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- org.icefaces:icefaces-ace:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.icefaces:icefaces:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.glassfish:javax.faces:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.portlet:portlet-api:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.icepush:icepush:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.icefaces:icefaces-compat:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.icefaces:icefaces:jar:3.2.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] \- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.440s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Mar 06 13:24:47 GMT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/120M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*** Update 2 ***

I had the following version installed in Juno:

```
m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.3.0.**20130129-0926** org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e
```

Added the link in the answer on the post pointed to by @eis Did a Check for updates. Eclipse showed there was a minor update available (**1.3.1.20130219-1424**). But the update failed with the following error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.ning.async-http-client,1.6.5.20130219-0923
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common,1.3.1.20130219-0923
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.core,1.3.1.20130219-1424
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui,1.3.1.20130219-1424
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.discovery,1.3.1.20130219-1424
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor,1.3.1.20130219-1424
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml,1.3.1.20130219-1424
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.jdt,1.3.1.20130219-1424
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.launching,1.3.1.20130219-1424
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.lifecyclemapping.defaults,1.3.1.20130219-1424
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer,1.3.1.20130219-0923
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime,1.3.1.20130219-0923
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.model.edit,1.3.1.20130219-1424
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.refactoring,1.3.1.20130219-1424
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.scm,1.3.1.20130219-1424
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.jboss.netty,3.2.5.Final-20130219-0923
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.m2e.feature,1.3.1.20130219-1424
```

So, I uninstalled the existing m2e and reinstalled it. This worked. Also included

```
m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional) 1.3.1.20130219-1424 org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e
```

But the issue remains. Juno is still deploying javax.servlet-api3.0.1.jar :(

---

#### Solved

(Disclaimer first: This is my understanding. Happy to be corrected)

It appears m2e + m2e extras (not sure if they are separate entities still, or just m2e) was already installed with Juno. I had to install [m2e - wtp connector](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/) for things to work properly. Maven scopes are now honoured.

Install m2e-wtp connector: In Juno - Window > Preferences > Maven > Discovery > Open Catalog > Select the check box against m2e-wtp connector to install it. This adds the following to the installed software

```
m2e-wtp - Maven Integration for WTP (Incubation)    0.17.0.20130212-1821    org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e-wtp
```

Comment: how you are building war file?

Comment: I am not building a war file. I have a Tomcat 7.0.30 server configured in Eclipse. I right click on the Tomcat server entry in the Servers tab > Add / Remove add the project, publish and start Tomcat. The jar file gets deployed with other dependencies although in this case it is marked as provided.

Comment: Could you show your `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`?

Comment: Added to the original post above (Update 1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent duplicate servlet jar using eclipse+m2eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905579/how-to-prevent-duplicate-servlet-jar-using-eclipsem2eclipse)

Comment: Thanks @eis I noticed that answer was posted May 2011. Could have been for the previous Eclipse release perhaps (??). Anyway, I added that update site to Juno and checked. see Update 2 in my original post.

Comment: +1 for the followup - this way it is probably useful to someone else, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, this is not a Maven issue. Maven gets that servlet-api is provided, but you're not deploying or building a package through maven, you're only compiling with maven (and doing that through m2e perhaps) and deploying through Eclipse. m2e/eclipse should handle this issue but isn't.

According to this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905579/how-to-prevent-duplicate-servlet-jar-using-eclipsem2eclipse), installing m2e + m2e-extras should fix it. Also see the other answers for more details on Eclipse behavior.

Comment: m2e-extras may be relevant to previous Eclipse release.. It doesn't show up on the list for Juno when using the update site. Have posted more details in *** Update 2 *** above. I'm working through the responses at the given thread. Fingers crossed.

Comment: I'll accept @eis' answer as it pointed me to the right area. I have provided an update in my original post should anyone using Juno experience the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<artifactId/>` is wrong in both places.

- The tag ordering convention (which, of course is not enforced strictly) is to define artifacts' and exclusions' tags in the following ordering `groupId`, `artifactId`, `version`, `type`, `classifier`, `scope`. Yours is `artifactId`, `groupId`. I suggest you correct this and follow the convention for readability's sake.
- Change your exclusion as follows:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>icefaces-ace</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
      <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
              <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
              <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Change your dependency to:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  ```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @carlspring. <1> I agree about the ordering. I found that the POM editor in Juno is doing that when exclusions are marked (Right click an entry in the Dependency Hierarchy tab and select Exclude Maven artifact). I have edited the POM file to set the order. However, the issue remains. javax.servlet-api jar continues to get deployed onto the lib folder of the webapp. <2> It appears the artifactId has changed starting version 3. Up to 2.x it was servlet-api. Starting 3.0.1 it is javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar

Comment: Ha! Who came up with the odd naming...?! Thanks for pointing that out concerning versions >= 3.x. Well, perhaps your exclusion should then be for the older `servlet-api` only?

Comment: icefaces:3.2.0 was pulling in javax.servlet-api:3.0.1 as a transitive. So my assumption was that excluding that and adding it explicitly with provided scope would make it available in the project workspace but not deploy to Tomcat.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not quite sure what's happening. Sorry. What you've done is what I would have done myself.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for your time. At least it validates my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Eclipse Juno and installing "m2e - wtp" plugin solved my problem too.