# jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat7

I am running a Maven project which is also a dynamic web project. I have used all Spring libraries in Maven. I created `web.xml`, but when I start my Tomcat 7 server I am getting the following message:

```
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\mibvzd0\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\
org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\hapi_hl7\WEB-INF\lib\
servlet-api-2.4.jar) - jar not loaded.
See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

I tried deleting the servlet from `webapp/lib`, but it didn't work. Let me know what should be done in my case.

Comment: Note that this behavior is according to the servlet specification.  A full understanding is helpful in understanding the more tricky problems you may run into.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: Servlet Jar not Loaded... Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993493/error-servlet-jar-not-loaded-offending-class-javax-servlet-servlet-class)

Answer (score 117):

The servlet API .jar file must not be embedded inside the webapp since, obviously, the container already has these classes in its classpath: it implements the interfaces contained in this jar.

The dependency should be in the `provided` scope, rather than the default `compile` scope, in your Maven pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: "The dependency should be in the provided scope, rather than the default compile scope, in your Maven pom." How can I do that

Comment: See my edited answer. clean and build the app using Maven, and check that the servlet jar is not in the WEB-INF/lib directory in the generated webapp.

Comment: I did everything. yet I am finding the jar in WEB-INF/lib directory. If I remove the jar I am getting below message    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
 Is there anything I need to do?

Comment: Maybe you have a dependency that has a transitive dependency to another servlet jar version. Use mvn dependency:tree to find where this servlet jar comes from, and add an exclusion.

Comment: how do I do the same for ivy?

Comment: look this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33222718/2692914 if you are using child projects or inheritance in Maven

Comment: Documenation on [Dependency Scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)

Answer (score 21):

You get this warning message when the servlet api jar file has already been loaded in the container and you try to load it once again from `lib` directory.

> The Servlet specs say you are not allowed to have ***servlet.jar*** in
>   your webapps `lib` directory.

- Get rid of the warning message by simply removing `servlet.jar` from your `lib` directory.
- If you don't find the jar in the `lib` directory scan for your build path and remove the jar.

---

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\project\WEB-INF\lib
```

If you are running a maven project, change the `javax.servlet-api` dependency to scope `provided` in you pom.xml since the container already provided the servlet jar in itself.

Answer (score 4):

To fix it, set the **scope** to **provided**. This tells Maven use code servlet-api.jar for compiling and testing only, but NOT include it in the WAR file. The deployed container will “provide” the servlet-api.jar at runtime.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may find the following windows command line useful in tracking down the offending jar file.  it creates an index of all the class files in all the jars in the folder.  Execute from within the lib folder of your deployed app, then search the index.txt file for the offending class.

```
for /r %X in (*.jar) do (echo %X & jar -tf %X) >> index.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

[Maven Dependency Scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)

> **provided** : This is much like compile, but indicates you ***expect*** the **JDK** or a **container** to provide the dependency at runtime. For example,
>   when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you
>   would set the dependency on the ***Servlet* API** and related Java EE APIs
>   to scope **provided** because ***the web container provides those classes***.
>   This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath,
>   and is not transitive.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this issue and I've tried numerous "solutions".

However, in the end, the only one that worked and it actually took a few seconds to do it was to: **delete and add back new server instance**!

Basically, I right clicked on my Tomcat server in Eclipse under Servers and deleted it. Next, I've added a new Tomcat server. Cleaned and redeployed the application and I got rid of this error.

Comment: Right click on your server -> Clean... and then again right click on your server -> clean tomcat work directory fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

Check Inside the Following Directory for the jar file el-api.jar  :C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\lib\el-api.jar  if it exists then in this directory of your web application  WEB-INF\lib\el-api.jar   the jar should be removed

Answer (score 0):

when your URL pattern is wrong, this error may be occurred.

eg. If you wrote @WebServlet("login"), this error will be shown. The correct one is @WebServlet("/login").

Answer (score 0):

*Exclusions and `provided` dependencies will not work in child projects.*

If you are using inheritance in Maven projects you *must* include this configuration on the parent `pom.xml` file. You  will have a `<parent>...</parent>` section in your pom.xml *if you are using inheritance*. So you will have something like this in your parent `pom.xml`:

```
<groupId>some.groupId</groupId>
<version>1.0</version>
<artifactId>someArtifactId</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>child-module-1</module>
    <module>child-module-2</module>
</modules>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

The JAX-WS dependency library “jaxws-rt.jar” is missing.

Go here http://jax-ws.java.net/.
Download JAX-WS RI distribution.
Unzip it and copy “jaxws-rt.jar” to Tomcat library folder “{$TOMCAT}/lib“.
Restart Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you see this message, it is benign.
If it says

```
INFO: validateJarFile(/<webapp>/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. 
See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

It means it is ignoring your servlet-api-2.5.jar because tomcat already has a built-in version of that jar, so it isn't going to be using yours.  Typically this doesn't cause an issue.

If however it says `WEB-INF/lib/my_jar.jar - jar not loaded...Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class`

then what you can do (in my instance, it's a shaded jar) is run

$ mvn dependency:tree

and discover that you have a transitive dependency on "something" that depends on a jar that is either servlet-api or something like it (ex: `tomcat-servlet-api-9.0.0`).  So add an exclusion to that to your pom, ex: (in my case, tomcat, in your case, probably the ones mentioned in the other answers):

```
 <dependency>
    ...
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9941668/778517

I did `mvn dependency:tree` and result was

```
(...)
[INFO] +- org.zkoss.zk:zkspring-core:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.5-RC2:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:0.9.9:runtime
[INFO] |     |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:0.9.9:runtime
[INFO] |     +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |     \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
(...)
```

so in pom.xml, zkspring-core I added the exclusions tag

```
(...)
             <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
             <artifactId>zkspring-core</artifactId>
             <version>3.2.0</version>
+            <exclusions>
+                <exclusion>
+                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
+                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
+                </exclusion>
+            </exclusions>
             </dependency>
(...)
```

after I ran `mvn dependency:tree` and javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile is clean

```
(...)
[INFO] +- org.zkoss.zk:zkspring-core:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.5-RC2:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:0.9.9:runtime
[INFO] |     |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:0.9.9:runtime
[INFO] |     \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:1.4:compile
(...)
```

Answer (score -4):

Remove `servlet.jar` from source `web-inf/lib` folder as it is available in tomcat `lib` folder then it works fine

Comment: This answer does not add anything that isn't already in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16710657/4751173).