# Trouble with heroku webapp-runner launching war

Tags: heroku, wavemaker

I'm trying to launch a *very simple* Wavemaker war using directions from a Heroku tutorial: [Deploying Tomcat-based Java Web Applications with Webapp Runner](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner)

This tutorial uses the following java syntax to run a war:
    $ java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/*.war

When I deploy to Heroku or run this command locally I get the same misbehaviour.  The page opens with a never ending spinning timer. The app never starts.

I would have posted a screen-shot of this but I apparently do not have enough "stack-overflow points." :(.  This [link](http://dev.wavemaker.com/forums/?q=node/10833#comment-37488) has an attachment that has the screen shot.

```
11:53:12.52>java -jar .\lib\webapp-runner.jar --port 8080 .\dist\*.war
Adding Context / for .\dist\HerokuTest.war 
Apr 30, 2013 11:54:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Apr 30, 2013 11:54:20 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Apr 30, 2013 11:54:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Apr 30, 2013 11:54:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.30
Apr 30, 2013 11:54:26 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Documents and Settings\rbroersma\WaveMaker 6.5.3.Release\projects\HerokuTest\target\tomcat.8080\work\Tomcat\localhost\_\WEB-INF\lib\webapp-runner.jar)
- jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Apr 30, 2013 11:54:26 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
INFO: No global web.xml found
Apr 30, 2013 11:54:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Apr 30, 2013 11:54:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Apr 30, 2013 11:54:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'springapp'
Apr 30, 2013 11:54:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO:  Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

Any thoughts how I can correct this problems?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the issue is not Heroku; it's most likely caused by your build including the servlet-api jar.  Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601469/jar-not-loaded-see-servlet-spec-2-3-section-9-7-2-offending-class-javax-serv), it should help you solve the problem.