# RMI from Tomcat to Weblogic

Tags: tomcat, servlets, weblogic, rmi, war

I have a webapp that is integrating with a RMI interface on a weblogic server. During development I used the wlfullclient.jar and everything was fine.

But as I deployed the war on Tomcat I encountered a problem:
`validateJarFile(.../wlfullclient-10.3.2.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3 ...Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class`

So wlfullclient.jar has its own implementation of javax.servlet.Servlet and Tomcat doesnt like it.

What can I do? Without wlfullclient.jar I get
`javax.sercurity.auth.login.LoginException: Login failure: all modules ignored`

I have tried using wlthint3client.jar, wls-api.jar, wlclient.jar. Doesn't seem to work, my integration tests wont work. Any ideas?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601469/jar-not-loaded-see-servlet-spec-2-3-section-9-7-2-offending-class-javax-serv and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137296/deploy-and-running-jar-application-in-weblogic

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp Duplicate of your first link, but the other one? The relevance of citing an unanswered question that is not about this topic escapes me.

Comment: It's called a copy paste error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked now. I did the following

1. Modified wlfullclient.jar: removed javax-package. Pretty bad but I cannot seem to find an alternative. Neither the wlthinclient or wlclient works.
2. Added the following packages

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
       <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
       <version>3.0</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.security.jacc</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.security.jacc-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.4</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
       <artifactId>transaction-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.1</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

step1:
java -jar WL_HOME/server/lib/wljarbuilder.jar
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/client/jarbuilder.html

step2:
using 7-zip open wlfullclient.jar and then delete javax.el and javax.servlet folders
http://blog.csdn.net/weijianiu/article/details/7846482

step3:
enjoy