# explain what jars file must be present in web - inf lib folder so that my servlet should run properly?

Tags: java, servlets, jar

INFO: validateJarFile(C:\jakarta-tomcat-5.5.7\webapps\nikhil1\WEB-INF\lib\servle
t-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending clas
s: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

Comment: No, never put servlet-api.jar in lib folder. Your server will take care of it automatically, it will be in your server's lib directory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601469/jar-not-loaded-see-servlet-spec-2-3-section-9-7-2-offending-class-javax-serv)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that the application server (for example, Tomcat) has already loaded the `servlet-api.jar` in the classpath.

To get rid of the error, just remove the jar from the `WEB-INF/lib` folder and restart the server.