# What does this jar not loading error mean?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, servlets

**Error**

```
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\gopir\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\
      org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\hapi_hl7\WEB-INF\lib\
      servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded.
      See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet  /Servlet.class
```

It means that `servlet-api` is already loaded. So duplication causing this issue.

If I am wrong, please correct me.

**My Error**

```
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\gopir\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\
org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\hapi_hl7\WEB-INF\lib\
myApp.jar) - jar not loaded.
See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet  /Servlet.class
```

This is my error. Does it mean that myApp.jar is already added and trying to add it again is an error. Or servlet-api jar is dupliated.

Please help me to understand this.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601469/jar-not-loaded-see-servlet-spec-2-3-section-9-7-2-offending-class-javax-serv

Answer (score 0):

A war can't contains jar related to servlets.

Remove `servlet-api-2.4.jar` from `WEB-INF/lib` to solve this problem.

It happens because the servlet container (tomcat, jetty, jboss...) has it's own `servlet-api.jar` and you can't override it.

If you are using maven try this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>YOUR_SERVLET_VERSION</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The provided scope inform that the jar must be excluded from the war at package time.

Comment: There is no such jar under `wtpwebapps/.../myProjet/web-inf/lib`.