# ervlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am not using maven to build my project and i require the session variable that why i need servlet-api.jar file in the build path . But when i am configuring using it maven its throwing me the error

```
servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

the code for session variable

```
(session.getAttribute("surveyDesc")
```

just because stackoverflow was not allowing me to post the question else .

Comment: you need servlet-api.jar file at your class path, because of absent it, you are getting error while work with session..., please provide servlet-api.jar at your class path.

Comment: when i am adding it it's throwing me this error servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

Comment: right now where did you placed servlet-xx.jar into your application, is it into "web-inf/lib" ?

Comment: If you're not using maven, how do you build your project? As can be found in several [other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993493/error-servlet-jar-not-loaded-offending-class-javax-servlet-servlet-class) this may be related to whatever build system you're using trying to deploy the servlet-api.jar file. That file should be available at compiletime, but not distributed as that will cause the conflict you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this dependency  and check it should work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i am not using maven

Comment: @abhishek oops i think you should look at this link it will resolve your issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601469/jar-not-loaded-see-servlet-spec-2-3-section-9-7-2-offending-class-javax-serv