# Eclipse copies jars which are in provided scope to WEB-INF/lib in tomcat deploy directory

Tags: eclipse, maven-3, tomcat6

We have servlet-api*.jar and jsp-api*.jar as provided scope in our maven project. These jars are also copied along with others into WEB-INF/lib folder in the tomcat webapps/APP/WEB-INF/lib folder. How to avoid copying these jars

Comment: Could you please provide your *pom.xml* file?

Comment: As i am in the restricted development place, i don't see any option to share the file. Also i'm not able to copy&paste the pom file here in the post

Comment: I see that eclipse 3.8 is working fine as expected but not in 4.4. So do i need to alter anything in eclipse?

Comment: Without your POM file is very difficult to be of any help... Can't you hide any sensitive information that you may have on your *pom.xml* and edit your post with it?

Comment: even after i hide the sensitive information, it is still too big to post here. But  i can share one more thing about what is happening. When i run maven install and checked the war, i don't see those jars marked as provided. So these jars copied by eclipse some xxx plugin to tomcat webapps folder :(

Comment: Trim your POM: remove all unrelated dependencies. Just leave the plugin configurations and mentioned dependencies.

Comment: Went through the same issue and found the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905579/how-to-prevent-duplicate-servlet-jar-using-eclipsem2eclipse).